# copy last command in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I can see the last command in the terminal by pressing `up arrow` as in the following example:

I typed `cd /`:

```
Makss-Mac:~ maks$ cd /
```

... pressed `enter`, command `cd /` executed and now I can press `up arrow` and see the command `cd /` again:

```
Makss-Mac:/ maks$ cd /
```

I want to not only see the last command but also copy it to the clipboard.

Maybe there exists a shortcut that not only shows the last command in the terminal (as `up arrow` does) but at the same time copies it to the clipboard.

Or maybe there is a shortcut for selecting all from current terminal line. And so I would be able to copy the last command (after pressing `up arrow`) by pressing `super+c`. Of course I can select it with the mouse. But when commands are 10 times longer than `cd /` it can be too time-consuming, especially if you do it every 30 seconds.

Or is there maybe a way to write a plugin for the terminal?

Comment: It might be easier to find a solution here if you could add some details about what you intend to do with the content of the clipboard afterwards. Where are you going to paste it to?

Comment: yes to paste it to another terminal tab

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put this into your `~/.bashrc` `~/.bash_profile` or where-ever you like it:

```
alias copyLastCmd='fc -ln -1 | awk '{$1=$1}1' | pbcopy '
```

After opening a new window (or running `source ~/.bash_profile`) you should be able to run `copyLastCmd` and have the command in the clipboard.

To explain what's going on: you're basically using "fix command" (`fc`) to get you the last command, remove both leading and trailing whitespace for nicer formatting with `awk` and then copy it into your Mac's pasteboard with `pbcopy`.

**EDIT:**

Now that we know that you want to copy to paste into another terminal tab, there's another option:
Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` `~/.bash_profile` or where-ever you like it:

```
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND='$PROMPT_COMMAND; history -a; history -n'
```

Then, once you have some new tabs open (let's call them "tab A" and "tab B"):

1. Execute any command in tab A
2. Switch to tab B, press enter on an *empty* line, giving you a "fresh" new line (and thus re-evaluating the history)
3. use the up arrow once and you should have the command you've just entered in tab A.

**EDIT 2:**
I've replaced the usage of `sed` with `awk` in the original answer above, to take care of both leading and trailing whitespace .

Comment: That's a great alias! To cut off the trailing new line, so you can edit the command after pasting, I used `awk`: `alias copyLastCmd='fc -ln -1 | sed '1s/^[[:space:]]*//' | awk 1 ORS="" | pbcopy '`

Comment: @nwinkler: OH you're right, should've used awk: `fc -ln -1 | awk '{$1=$1}1'` will remove both trailing and leading whitespace.

Comment: had to modify the alias for special chars `alias copyLastCmd="fc -ln -1 | awk '{\$1=\$1}1' | pbcopy"`. still gets my upvote

Comment: I used this until I did a "git -reset --hard" on one terminal and in another "unsuspecting git folder" pressed up arrow and enter hastily as I thought I was running a script I was using before. You can imagine what happened, and that was the last time I used this shared "global" history

Comment: @MrGigu happened to me with a "local" history where I pressed the "up" arrow twice, instead of once, accidentally - lessons learned the hard way, I guess.

Comment: Someone should edit the answer and apply the fix Asmus suggested. This alias was working in some cases and failing in others until I came back here and read the comments. Not sure what the policy is but the correct answer is really

`alias copyLastCmd="fc -ln -1 | awk '{\$1=\$1}1' | pbcopy"`

Comment: @ejkitchen Not sure how that backslash escape is working correctly for you or @MrGigu - in my shell, awk will throw a syntax error if I'm using `\ ` within a single-quoted statement. It would work, however, when using `"` instead of `'`. Does this work in your shell without syntax error: `echo "test 'test'" | awk '{printf \$1}'` ?

Comment: @Asmus, just copied the text from @MrGigu and what I pasted in my terminal window and works great. When I type what you wrote, I get the following

```awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {printf >>>  \ <<< $1}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

and when I paste in Ubuntu 20.xx, I get the following

```
awk: 1: unexpected character '\'
```

Comment: @ejkitchen huh, what a weird issue with shell escape characters - turns out that if I directly execute the command without aliasing it first (i.e. run `fc -ln …`) _including the backslashes_ in a new terminal window, the command will throw an error, however if I add it as an alias to my `.bash_profile` exactly the same (i.e. with backslash), *it works* afterwards. If I try executing the `alias …` line (w/ backslash) directly in a terminal session, it *looks ok* (i.e. using `type copyLastCmd` it _looks fine_) but it does not work at all. Weird. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 15):

This will use [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) to grab the last command and echo it. You can pipe to `pbcopy` to save the last command to your clipboard.

```
> echo !! | pbcopy
```

If you want a command from your history that was not the *last* one, you can run:

```
> history
```

And reference the desired command number like:

```
> echo !5 | pbcopy
```

Comment: It may be your favorite, and it may even work, but you need to supply a little explication about what the command _actually does_, and how the OP (who accepted one of the answers five years ago) can use it effectively.

Comment: @IconDaemon good call. I think this is worth adding to an old question because it is simpler than the accepted answer since it does not require any profile customization.

Comment: If you want the second to last command: `echo !-2 | pbcopy`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another take based on the answer by @Asmus. To make his alias work in my bash script, I had to use a bit of quoting, since single quotes don't work in a single-quoted alias without some additional quoting:

```
alias copyLastCmd='fc -ln -1 | awk '\''{$1=$1}1'\'' | pbcopy'
```

The `'\''` will basically close the current quote, then add an escaped quote, and then open the actual quote again.

The above version will copy the last command to your clipboard, and once you paste it, it's immediately executed, since it will have a *newline* at the end.

To get rid of the newline at the end, so you can actually edit the command before running it, you can do the following:

```
alias copyLastCmd='fc -ln -1 | awk '\''{$1=$1}1'\'' ORS='\'''\'' | pbcopy'
```

The `ORS=''` (that's without the quoting) will strip off the trailing newline character, so you can edit the pasted text before running it.

Comment: Thank you for this - none of the above solutions worked for me. You've helped me save a lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

I came here as came up with Sam Berry's exact same answer, but it doesn't work for me (OSX 10.14.6).

Managed to get it to do so with quotes around the `!!` :

`echo "!!" | pbcopy`

Answer (score 3):

You can set your history to ignore commands that start with a space:

```
export HISTIGNORE=' *'
```

And then run the following command to git the last command to the clipboard (make sure you have a space at the beginning):

```
history 1 | cut -d " " -f 4- | pbcopy
```

You probably would then want to save the command as an alias to make it easier to remember.